# custom alert dialog getting unwanted padding

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have tried to make a custom alert dialog and it mostly works very well. the functionality is working perfectly but the view is behaving in a weird way. The dialog layout consists of a button and a listview. as you will see in the screenshot below the button is getting a margin on top and bottom.

i dont see any reason for these margins, and i would greatly appreciate some help :)

for some reason i cant post my xml layout but i can asure you that it contains no paddings or margins of any kind

Java Code :

```
View dialogView = ((LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.choose_catagory_dialog_layout, null, false);
Button footerButton = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.choose_catagory_dialog_footer_button);
footerButton.setOnClickListener(ButtonClickEvent);

builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setView(dialogView);
builder.setTitle(R.string.choose_catagory);

builder.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter, ListclickEvent);
alert = builder.create();
alert.getListView().setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
alert.setOwnerActivity((Activity) mContext);
```

Screenshot:

[image: http://cl.ly/3S2y3p3E0e3H2o1I272m]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The CustomPanel of an `AlertDialog` has a 5dp top and bottom padding. You can override these using:

```
alert.setView(dialogView, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: ok but this is method of the AlertDialog class and not AlertDialog.builder , so how to invoke that method?

Comment: It is part of AlertDialog.builder:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView(android.view.View)

You would replace your 4th line with what pcans has above.

Comment: as stated in linked document, the setView() method of AlertDialog.builder is setView(View) Though AlertDialog contains the method setView(View,int,int,int,int) . how do i access this method from AlertDialog.builder?

Comment: stupid of me, forget that last qeustion. thanks you so much for your help!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on devices with HTC Sense, the padding is still there.

Comment: The only way I could do this was calling `AlertDialog.Builder.create()` to get the AlertDialog instance.

Comment: @JKM are you sure it is part of AlertDialog.builder? The link you provided also doesn't support your argument..

Comment: I posted the answer over a year ago, it's probably outdated by now and needs to be updated. Unfortunately, I no longer do Android development actively.

Comment: Thanks, my old mistake is corrected. setview(View, int, int, int, int) must be called on alert object, not builder.

Answer (score 11):

For me, it seemed that `builder.setView(dialogView, 0, 0, 0, 0);` is set to `@hide` and not available. In the end, I had to set the padding of my custom view's parent after calling `show()`

For example:

```
// Inflate custom dialog view
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
CustomDialogView dialogView = (CustomDialogView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);

// Create and show custom alert dialog
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
builder.setView(dialogView);
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, this);
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel, this);
builder.show();

// Remove padding from parent
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)dialogView.getParent();
parent.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: For some reason the padding remains. Anyone has better solution?

Answer (score 2):

Here is code that will give you full control over the dialog view:

```
final Dialog dlg = new Dialog(this);
View action_layout = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.contacts_action, null);
dlg.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
Window window = dlg.getWindow();
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
window.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();
wlp.gravity = Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL;
window.setAttributes(wlp);
dlg.setCancelable(true);
dlg.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
dlg.setContentView(action_layout);
dlg.show();
```