# Remove spaces on the top and the bottom of the items in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have an `AlertDialog` with items provided by `ArrayAdapter`. When I show the `AlertDialog`, there are spaces on top and bottom of the items. I want to remove them completely. Sure, changing the color of `AlertDialog` background to match the item's background would do the trick but I want to remove it completely. This is the said spaces:

[image]

This is the style for AlertDialog: (colorPrimaryLight is the spaces' color)

```
<style name="style_alert_dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>
</style>
```

Layout used for ArrayAdapter (template_alert_dialog_item):

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTextWhite"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryNormal"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:padding="10dp">
</TextView>
```

Code I used:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ReviewMeTooMainPage.this, R.layout.template_alert_dialog_item, 
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items));
                AlertDialog.Builder b = new Builder(ReviewMeTooMainPage.this, R.style.style_alert_dialog);
                View inflatedTemplate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template_textview,(
                        ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_page_display),false);
                TextView textView = inflatedTemplate.findViewById(R.id.template_title);
                b.setCustomTitle(textView);

                b.setAdapter(adapter, new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                });

                b.show();
```

I tried to use:

```
AlertDialog dialog = b.show();
                dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

but no prevail.

How can I remove those borders?

Comment: please try set the margin  to 0 too )

Comment: can you show the layout.template_textview file?

Comment: Maybe there is margin or padding from your `template_textview.xml`

Comment: this might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329272/custom-alert-dialog-getting-unwanted-padding

Comment: @Tepits I didn't use any of that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836938/remove-border-padding-from-dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a custom layout, this padding will disappeared. It's because of using `setAdapter`. Because it uses default ListView in AlertDialog builder. So, you can put a ListView in content layout and set it to the AlertDialog like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_people_info, (ViewGroup) mRootView, false);

ListView personListView = viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.people_listView);
ListAdapter listAdapter = new PersonAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.person_lsit_item, personsInfo);
personListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

builder.setView(viewInflated);
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.action_close, (dialog, which) -> dialog.cancel());

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Comment: This does the trick. I change my code to use `setView() and use ListView.`

Answer (score 0):

Removing:

```
android:padding="10dp"
```

In the `TextView` would probably help since the padding is in the content (`TextView`) in your case.

If it didn't help, try removing this:

```
<item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
```

Comment: if that is the case, then that should appear on left and right side as well right?

Comment: @Kannan_SJD yeah true, I removed it and it's still there.